# JMeter make random number return float

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have this:

```
  "latitude": ${__Random(-85,85)},
  "longitude": ${__Random(-180,180)},
```

I would like to have this:

```
  "latitude": ${__Random(42.06,42.08)},
  "longitude": ${__Random(20.02,20.04)},
```

but it does not work. How to change it to have a random number between 42.06 - 42.08 and 20.02 and 20.04 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need that limited random values just use static prefix like `20.0` and call [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function to generate the postfix, like:

```
"latitude": 42.0${__Random(6,8,)},
"longitude": 20.0${__Random(2,4,)},
```

---

If you're looking for a way to generate fully random latitude and longitude values I would recommend switching to [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function like:

```
"latitude": ${__javaScript((Math.random() * (180) - 90).toFixed(2) * 1,)},
"longitude": ${__javaScript((Math.random() * (360) - 180).toFixed(2) * 1,)},
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on above and other JMeter Functions.